# LDU Factorization in MatLab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I am working on a project in linear systems which requires me to do LDU Decomposition on a given 6x6 matrix. For the first part of the project he wants wants this computed fully by hand. What I am having trouble with is the second part where we are meant to be doing it using for-loops in matlab. We are given random 6x6 and 15x15 matrices and asked to find L D U and their inverses in addition to he inverse of our original matrix. "The MATLAB script must find these via row operations computed inside for-loops, you absolutely ma not use inv(), rref(), or other such commands." Can someone give me some basics tips as to where I should begin?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2360-the-matrix-computation-toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
A = rand(6,6); % random 6x6 matrix

[L,U,~] = lu(A); % do an LU decomposition, using MATLAB's lu method.
D = diag(diag(U)); % take the diagonal components of matrix U and store them in the diagonal matrix D 
U = inv(D)*U; % clean the U matrix as follows
```

Comment: The problem here is that he wants us to do it using forloops, not using matlabs commands built specifically for this. Essentially row-swapping and doing gauss elimination "manually"

Comment: who's "he" ? @Slumped

Comment: the professor that assigned the project. I'm not asking for my project to be completed for me but I'm just looking for a push in the right direction as to how to use for-loops for this purpose.

Comment: the hint i can give is that the pivoting (row-swapping) happens in the lu() MATLAB function. Read more about this function.

Comment: Why ~? @AhmadBazzi

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

Create a matrix:

```
M = rand(6,6);
```

Extract the i-th column from this matrix:

```
c = M(:,i)
```

Extract the j-th line from this matrix:

```
v = M(j,:)
```

Matrix multiply them (kinda like a dot product)

```
prod = v*c
```

Get elements from 2 to 6 (end) in the j-th line:

```
v2 = M(j,2:end)
```

Hope this helps.